# Unable to get the current margin-left?

Tags: javascript

In my simple code, I am trying to get the marginLeft of a certain image, but it alerts "undefined" instead of 300, which it should alert (the margin-left is 300 in the css)

Here is my code, thanks

```
var Left = document.getElementById("Shot").style.marginLeft;
var ParsedLeft = parseInt(Left)
alert(ParsedLeft)
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a demo here http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N4nH8/

Comment: In your fiddle, its not shouting the alert message.

Comment: `No wrap - in <body>`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the style the way you're trying only works for inline CSS. For CSS set via a stylesheet, use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
var Left = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Shot"));
console.log(Left.marginLeft)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/N4nH8/1/)**

Comment: Still returning undefined when I use it, but it is working on jsFiddle for some reason

Comment: Are you loading your JavaScript in the proper place? What errors does your console show you?

Comment: I have the exact code as the fiddler with added <script> tags

Comment: Do you have it in the head or the end of the body? If it's in the head, then the first four lines won't be getting any values since they're referencing elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the number without "px" or "em" you could do this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Shot');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
var left = style.getPropertyValue('margin-left');
left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
console.log(left);
```

The way you were trying to do it is for inline CSS.